# android when trying drawing a text on it using canvas i get an error

Tags: android, text-rendering

I tried drawing text on an image, but it doesn't work. Here is my code:

```
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://mms.first/"+R.drawable.girl);
    Bitmap bitmap;
    try {
         ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        bitmap = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(cr, uri);

        //drawTextImage(bitmap);
         Canvas c = new Canvas(bitmap);
            Paint paint = new Paint();
            paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
            paint.setAntiAlias(true);
            paint.setTextSize(20);
            c.drawText("Golden Stag", 30, 200, paint);
        image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: Can you give us more details about your error ?

Comment: "Source not found." for this code line:  Canvas c = new Canvas(bitmap);

Comment: Where "android.resource://mms.first/" does come from ?

Comment: "android.resource://[package]/[res id]"

Comment: I have the image in drawable folder

Comment: Why not directly use setImageResourc method on your ImageView ? It's far easier

Comment: Bitmap bitmap;
Resources resx = getResources();
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resx, R.drawable.girl);
       
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code:

```
 Bitmap bitmap;
  Resources resx = getResources();
  bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resx, R.drawable.girl);

  Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true));
```